# Filtering pivot table results by organisation unit

Tags: dhis2

I am trying to create a filter to be used with the pivot table results, so that only the filtered OrgUnits will appear. For that I have created OrgUnit groups and have used them in the pivot table. The layout is illustrated in the attached file, by using the OrgUnits in the row dimensions. As a result, the pivot table is only using the OrgUnit groups as a categorization of the results but not filtering them as all OrgUnits are still displayed. I think that an interest using a filter is to avoid dumping a huge amount of data, which is sometimes freezing DHIS2 when displaying the results at the lowest level of OrgUnits.

Which way should I follow in order to filter the OrgUnits according to some criteria (like using a spreadsheet filter)? Would it be possible doing that in the pivot table or it would be worth creating an equivalent SQL uery? One constraint with using SQL View is that we can only call DataElements but not Indicators.

I am using DHIS2 2.24.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this I think you should use the "org unit group" selection mode. Under the organisation unit dimension section, click the gear icon and select "Select groups", then select the org unit group which contains the org units you would like to display.

In the org unit tree you can leave the selected org unit at the national level if you would like to include facilities from the entire country.

[image]